# Enable python pdb on emacs with virtualenv

Tags: python

While running pdb within emacs, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10313090/2476373) (`python -m pdb myscript.py`) is successful for enabling python pdb on emacs with virtualenv.

The problem is that I need to type it manually after calling `M-x pdb`

How could I edit my .emacs file to use it automatically, without the need to type it manually every time?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can choose the pdb command like this in your .emacs:

```el
(setq gud-pdb-command-name "python -m pdb myscript.py")
;;or let you choose the python script
(setq gud-pdb-command-name "python -m pdb ")
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried the 3rd option, but it doesn't work. When I type `M-x pdb` the result is `Run /usr/lib/python2.7/pdb.py (like this): /usr/lib/python2.7/pdb.py myscript.py` where I need to manually change to: `Run /usr/lib/python2.7/pdb.py (like this): python -m pdb myscript.py`

Comment: the pb is that gud history is used instead of gud-pdb-command-name. Try `M-x :  (setq gud-pdb-history nil)` and restart emacs with the above configuration.

Comment: I remove the third possibility because it doesn't work as expected

Comment: Thanks again, but I still get the same result (tried the 2nd option). Also, I couldn't type `M-x : (setq gud-pdb-history nil)`, so I entered it to my `.emacs` file instead.

Comment: Sorry `M-: (setq gud-pdb-history nil)`

Comment: I noticed that if I type `M-x pdb` within a non .py file, then your solution works. But when I type it within a .py it doesn't. Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: No idea, sorry !